# Flowplayer throwing error :Uncaught Flowplayer cannot access element

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, video, flowplayer

In my project, I am displaying video in many pages. But in one page it is throwing error as

```
Uncaught Flowplayer cannot access element: flowplayer flowplayer-3.2.13.min.js:22
b flowplayer-3.2.13.min.js:22
window.flowplayer.window.$f flowplayer-3.2.13.min.js:22
(anonymous function)
```

I saw lot of posts related to the same and tried according to them. But yet not able to solve this. I am sharing the part of code which is related to the flowplayer.

Code:

```
<script src="<?php echo base_url()?>js/flowplayer-3.2.13.min.js"></script>
<script>

    $f("flowplayer", {
    src:"<?php echo base_url()?>js/flowplayer-3.2.18.swf",
    wmode: "opaque"
},{
  clip: {

    autoPlay : "true",
    autoBuffering : "true",
    onStart: function() {
        return true;
      },

      onPause: function() {

      },

      onResume: function() {
      },

      onFinish: function() {

      }
  },
  });
</script>

<div class="video_playinga right">
    <div class="video_playinginner">
         <div class="video_frame">
            <div class="videoarea"> </div>
                <div class="shadow_v">
                <a href="<?php echo base_url()?>secure/1/teamwork.mp4" class="fplayer" id="flowplayer"></a>
            </div>
          </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I don't know whether these divs are making the problem. Can anyone help me to solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: **Flowplayer cannot access element**. Are you sure Flowplayer access elements after DOM loads? Or try to place the script after the HTML.

Comment: @RahilWazir..Thanks a lot. That was the problem. Now I placed the js after the div. Now it works.